# Swap first and last digits of a number( using loops)

Tags: python

How would you swap the first and last digits of a number using loops in python?
Eg. Input:2665
    Output:5662

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have a look into string slicing.

Comment: Is this some homework task? Why use loops in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
def swap(input_val):
    input_val = [i for i in str(input_val)]
    hold = input_val[0]
    input_val[0] = input_val[-1]
    input_val[-1] = hold
    input_val = ''.join(input_val)
    return int(input_val)

print(swap(2665))
```

Output:

```
5662
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a loop, you can use:

```
def swap(num):
    res = ""
    for ind, char in enumerate(str(num)):
        if ind == 0:
            last = char
        elif ind < len(str(num))-1:
            res += char
        else:
            res = char + res + last
    return int(res)
```

however, a much better way is to use slicing:

```
def swap(num):
    str_num = str(num)
    str_swapped = str_num[-1] + str_num[1:-1] + str_num[0]
    return int(str_swapped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using while loop:

```
def swap( num ):
    str_num = str( num )
    digits = []
    i = 0

    while( i < len( str_num ) ):
        digits.append( str_num[ i ] )
        i += 1

    digits[0], digits[ len( digits ) - 1 ] = digits[ len( digits ) - 1 ], digits[0]


    joined_digits = ''.join( digits )
    return int( joined_digits )

print( swap( 2665 ) )
```

Output:

```
 5662
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve your goal.

```
def swap(numbers):
    numbersList = []
    for number in str(numbers):
        numbersList.append(number)
    numbersList[0], numbersList[-1] = numbersList[-1], numbersList[0]
    return int(''.join(numbersList))
```

> **Test:** `print(swap(2665))`
>
> **Output:** 5662

Comment: While your code is working, the code in the loop only make a list of chars from the string, and the swapping part is done outside. You can replace the loop with `numbersList = list(str(numbers))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = input('enter any num : ')  
print(x[-1] + x[1:(len(x)-1)] +x[0])
```

Comment: This only works because x is a string, not a number. You will have to cast the number to string, do your manipulation and cast it back to a number if you want to use numbers. The input function always returns string btw.